# How do I initialize a doubly linked list from a text file in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

3rd SO question and still a programming noob. I've never used linked lists let alone doubly linked lists before. I've tried researching this question and all I seem to get are C++ or Java examples or programs that do way more than I'm asking to the point where it's confusing for a newbie. I'm given a text file with one value on each line. I've successfully read the file line by line using an fgets while loop and converted each data value to an integer using strtol in order to suit my data structure. How, then, do I assign these values to a doubly linked list?

My structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct value value_t;

struct value {
    int value;
    struct value *prev;
    struct value *next;
};
```

Do I need to create another structure for my links?
Do I initialize in the while loop?

So far I've read my values into an integer array and plan to use a for loop to initialize the structure but I'm unsure how to do that. Is this the right approach?

(Should be allocated on the heap)

Comment: For a linked list you need at least two things: A "head" which is a pointer to the first node in the list; And a marker to mark the last node in the list (usually a `NULL` next-node pointer). To add a new node at the end of the list you need to find the last node, and then make its next-node pointer point to the new node. It's helped if you have a "tail" pointer as well, which always points to the last node in the list.

Comment: Also, for exercises like these I really recommend using pen and paper to draw up all operations first. Use boxes as nodes, and arrows for links to the boxes (nodes). Erase and redraw the arrows as you manipulate the list.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
void InitializeListHead(value_t* head)
{
head->prev = head->next = head;
}

void InsertHeadList(value_t* head, value_t* val)
{
val->next = head->next;
head->next = val;
val->prev = head;
val->next->prev = val;
}

value_t init(int n, int* arr)
{
value_t result;
result.value = arr[0];
InitializeListHead(&result);

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
value_t* v = malloc(sizeof(value_t));
v->value = arr[i];
InsertHeadList(&result, v);
}

return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to have a different struct to reference the list itself, with pointers to the head and the tail. By convention, both pointers are NULL for an empty list. From there, you append a new element at the end of the list with the following operations:

- allocate a new node and set the value in it
- link it to the current tail (if the tail is not NULL)
- make it the new tail
- if head was NULL, make it the new head

Possible code:

```
struct list {
    value_t *head;
    value_t *tail;
};

value_t* append(struct list *lst, int val) {
    value_t *cur = malloc(sizeof(*cur));
    if (cur == NULL) return NULL;      // handle a possible allocation error
    cur->value = val;
    cur->next = NULL;
    cur->prev = lst->tail;
    if (lst->tail != NULL) lst->tail->next = cur;
    lst->tail = cur;
    if (lst->head == NULL) lst->head = cur;
    return cur;
}
```

Usage example:

```
struct list lst = {0};    // zero initialize the list
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    append(&lst, i);
}
```